# Value of Type has no member Delegate error

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols

So, I have the following code snippet:

```
protocol AllFiltersButtonsProtocol: AnyObject{
  func didTapReset()
  func didTapApply()
}

class AllFiltersUberResetApplyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  var delegate: AllFiltersButtonsProtocol?

  var leftButton: UIButton = {
    let leftButton = UIButton(.secondary, .large)
    leftButton.setTitle("Reset", for: .normal)
    leftButton.add(closureFor: .touchUpInside) { [self] in
      self.delegate.didTapReset()
    }
    return leftButton
  }()
```

But I am consistently getting the following error:

`Value of type '(AllFiltersUberResetApplyTableViewCell) -> () -> AllFiltersUberResetApplyTableViewCell' has no member 'delegate`  What is wrong with my code? Why is is it saying there is no member delegate when there clearly is a member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`leftButton` will be initialised before `UITableViewCell` is completely initialised and `self` exists. So You cannot use `self` inside `var leftButton: UIButton`. Try making it a `lazy var` to make sure that it gets called only when it is accessed for the first time.

```
lazy var leftButton: UIButton = {
    let leftButton = UIButton(.secondary, .large)
    leftButton.setTitle("Reset", for: .normal)
    leftButton.add(closureFor: .touchUpInside) { [self] in
      self.delegate.didTapReset()
    }
    return leftButton
  }()
```

Comment: Thank you @Jithin you nailed it!